# Establishing a MySQL connection without the MySql Connector for C++

Tags: c++, mysql, c++11, mfc

How can I connect to a MySql server from my MFC C++ (MSVC2013) **without** the MySql Connector?

I think it seems to be a stupid question, but no, I haven't found anything about this on Google, and the Oracle connector is very buggy and is a pain...

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `CDatabase` class to connect to your DB. Here is the example:

```
CDatabase cDb;

CString strConnectionString = _T("ODBC;DSN=DrumisD4WData;DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=DEV001-W2K8\\DRUMIS64;DATABASE=master");

TRY
{
 cDb.OpenEx(strConnectionString, CDatabase::noOdbcDialog);
 cDb.Close();
}
CATCH(CDBException, e)
{
 AfxMessageBox(e->m_strError);
}
END_CATCH;
```